# How to efficiently remove redundant linear constraints for optimization?

Tags: python, optimization, numpy

My optimization problem involves thousands of linear constraints. I want to reduce the complexity of my problem by finding redundant constraints, e.g. `3 * x + 4 * y < 10` would be redundant if I already have a constraint that is `4 * x + 5 * y < 10` (and `x` and `y` are `>= 0`, which is the case for my problem).

So, I have a numpy array that holds all the coefficients, and it looks like this, for example:

```
[[0.1, 3.0, 4.8, 0.2],
 [1.0, 4.7, 5.3, 0.1],
 [2.2, 4.3, 5.2, 1.1]]
```

representing the constraints:

```
0.1 * w + 3.0 * x + 4.8 * y + 0.2 * z < 10
1.0 * w + 4.7 * x + 5.3 * y + 0.1 * z < 10
2.2 * w + 4.3 * x + 5.2 * y + 1.1 * z < 10
```

How do I *efficiently* find out which one are redundant?

My common sense tells me to do a loop (pseudo-codeish):

```
for i, row1 in enumerate(array):
    for j, row2 in enumerate(array):
        if j > i:
            if all(row1 > row2):
                delete row
```

But this slow for thousands of constraints. Any way to speed it up?

Answer (score 2):

You can think of each constraint as a hyperplane, intercepting each axis at (sum constraint constant) / (coefficient for that axis); if the coefficient is 0, the hyperplane is parallel to that axis (== "intercepts at infinity").

Trivially, if the axis-intercepts for one hyperplane are all equal to or greater than the corresponding intercepts for another, that hyperplane is redundant.

In order to cull as many constraints as early as possible, you want to start by comparing against ones whose hyperplane is (a) as close to the origin as possible and (b) parallel to as few axes as possible, as it can only cull other hyperplanes also parallel to that axis. [A hyperplane not parallel to a given axis *may* be able to cull one parallel to that axis, but the inverse is never true.]

I suggest you sort the list by (number of axis-parallel axes) then (sum of non-infinite axis intercepts).

Comment: Sorting is a great idea, thanks. Unfortunately, in my example I gave the impression that I have plenty of coefficients that are 0. This is not the case, and almost all coefficients will have at least a small value. Your second sorting suggestion is still a very valuable one for me, though.

Comment: Now that I think about it more: since the sum of intercepts is just a heuristic, I still don't exactly know when I can break the loop, right? The only opportunity for that is when the maximum coefficient on row `j` is smaller than the sum of the coefficients on row `i`, but this will barely help me in my problem, I fear.

Answer (score 0):

I think for speed up this problem you can use `backtracking` for ex you can check out coefficients in arrays one by one ! if you find an index that is less than other index you can stop checking and delete the row !

Comment: Backticks are intended for code, not for emphasis. If you think that backtracking can be useful here, you had better explain in more detail, because your answer currently does not provide much help.

Comment: Going through the coefficients one by one will not work, since a coefficient that I haven't checked yet might be much higher and therefore dominate the constraint.